# How to make a database on c9.io

Tags: node.js, database, orientdb, c9.io

How can I make a database on `c9.io`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have here all docu about this:

https://community.c9.io/t/setting-up-phpmyadmin/1723

Basically:

```
mysql-ctl install
phpmyadmin-ctl install
mysql-ctl start
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a *temporary* MySQL Database in Cloud9 in the terminal using

```
mysql-ctl cli
```

See [Set Up a Database](https://docs.c9.io/docs/setup-a-database).
However, if you do not wish to learn MySQL, I would recommend [Getting Started](http://orientdb.com/getting-started/).